# Weird error when access the value of textfield swift

Tags: swift, textfield

```
import UIKit

protocol ChangeColor {
    func changeColor(color: UIColor)
}
class newItemTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet var nameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var priceTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var taxTextField: UITextField!

    var delegate: ChangeColor?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func name(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.changeColor(color: .link)
        if (priceTextField?.text == "" && nameTextField?.text == "" && taxTextField?.text == "") {
            delegate?.changeColor(color: .lightGray)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func price(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.changeColor(color: .link)
        if (priceTextField?.text == "" && nameTextField?.text == "" && taxTextField?.text == "") {
            delegate?.changeColor(color: .lightGray)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func tax(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.changeColor(color: .link)
        if (priceTextField?.text == "" && nameTextField?.text == "" && taxTextField?.text == "") {
            delegate?.changeColor(color: .lightGray)
        }
    }  

}
```

I am having the following error when trying to type in the textfields and deleting the text after. I don't understand why !

2020-05-24 10:30:14.587967+0200 invoice[3725:1111317] -[UITableViewCellContentView text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x104e07680
2020-05-24 10:30:14.588852+0200 invoice[3725:1111317] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCellContentView text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x104e07680'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1b6a34164 0x1b6748c1c 0x1b69327e0 0x1babadb6c 0x1b6a3885c 0x1b6a3ab60 0x102921044 0x102921430 0x1bab7f4c4 0x1ba569fe8 0x1ba56a350 0x1bae62214 0x1babacd68 0x1bae61dec 0x1babace48 0x1bae61c50 0x1babaca68 0x1bb0346f8 0x1bae60874 0x1bae1734c 0x1badff3b0 0x1badfff74 0x1bab7f4c4 0x1ba6aca20 0x1ba73c54c 0x1ba745b30 0x1ba742528 0x1ba741a70 0x1ba735430 0x1ba734bc4 0x1ba734980 0x1babbc044 0x1bab971cc 0x1bac19e0c 0x1bac1ca14 0x1bac14c88 0x1b69af860 0x1b69af7b4 0x1b69aef04 0x1b69a9ca4 0x1b69a9660 0x1c0dba604 0x1bab7e15c 0x10292d050 0x1b68251ec)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: do you have updated code on git ?

Comment: I have done it ! https://github.com/m4thus4n/project

Comment: where it is crashing >

Comment: On this if statement : if priceTextField?.text == "" && taxTextField?.text == "" {
            delegate?.changeColor(color: .lightGray)
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have connected wrong outlet to `taxTextField` Thats the main reason of application crash.

Connect your `taxTextField` to UITextField. you have connected to UIView.

[image]